# create extra wireless network connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i have two modems in my home and i want to combine and bridge them for more speed. i have just one wireless network connection in adaptor settings and whenever i connect to a wireless network, windows uses that unique wireless network connection for handle the internet so i can't highlight two connection for bridge them. what i should do?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is often called **WAN aggregation** which allows multiple WAN connections to be used simultaneously to perceive faster Internet by allowing the use of multipe connections for greater bandwidth.

You will need a capable multi-WAN router or appliance that can take both your Internet connection and converge them.